# Using free to deallocate a non char pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, free

While reading this [article](https://jblevins.org/mirror/cport), I came across this paragraph:

> Pointers to objects may have the same size but different formats. This
>   is illustrated by the code below:
>
> ```
> int *p = (int *) malloc(...); ... free(p);
> ```
>
> This code may malfunction in architectures where int * and char * have
>   different representations because free expects a pointer of the latter
>   type.

And this is not the first time I read that `free` expects a `char*` type.

My question is, how to free `p`?

Comment: `free` takes a `void *`, not a `char *`. Get a recent (i.e. not older than 18 years and about modern C) book. That will also explain the semantics and not to cast the result of `malloc` & friends.

Comment: But [`free`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free) expects a `void *` as argument. The article you link to is *very* old. Also, the likelihood of you ever finding a system where different pointer-types have different representations are slim to none (unless you want to specialize in ancient systems and computer archeology)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude even that the article is old, the writers are aware of the Standard C. So I guess the paragraph is wrong rather than old.

Comment: @BiteBytes But C wasn't really standardized until 1989 (ANSI) and 1990 (ISO), so by the the time the article was originally written there might have been plenty of pre-standard compilers available. Today the only widely available C compiler that's not up to modern standards is the Microsoft Visual Studio C compiler (it's still fully C89/90 compliant though).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The article was written in `Nov 1990, 8th Revision` and as I mentioned, the authors are aware of the Standard, and they have a whole section talking about ANSI C.

Comment: Well it *is* about portability, and at the time not all compilers were standards-compliant, which is probably the reason for the quotes you have. So to be portable (at that time) one could not assume that the `free` function took a `void *` argument (or that `malloc` returned a `void *`).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Sure, but the document also states that "we must restrict ourselves to programs which must execute under Unix-like operating systems and those which implement a reasonable Unix-like environment"... No modern-day Unix-like OS uses such prehistoric C compilers or standard libraries. I linked to the POSIX standard in my answer, which is the de-facto requirement for Unix-like OSes; in fact, if an OS is to be declared "Unix" it must adhere strictly to that manual.

Comment: I've favourited this question to ensure there's a chance for it to exist un-closed, as this is a very real problem that can be observed in the realm of C programming. Many students rely upon out-of-date resources, particularly those from developing nations such as India, and we need questions like these to hint to them that they should upgrade! @BiteBytes, you're not the only one, so it's great to see you're not taking this personally. Please let me know if this question gets closed and I don't notice.

Comment: @Seb That kind of my point. The document is old, and so is its information. Which you also point out in your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**NOTE**: [You should not cast the return value of `malloc` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

This question illustrates the dangers of reading potentially invalid resources. It's **extremely important** to ensure the resource you read is accurate! OPs resource in question, is *not wrong for its era*, but is *well out-of-date* and, consequently, *is invalid*. K&R 2E is ironically *one year older*, but is still *very much in date* (and thus still highly recommended) because it follows the standard.

If we consult [a more reputable resource (the `free` manual)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/free.html), we can see that `free` actually expects the pointer to be of `void *` type:

> ```
> void free(void *ptr);
> ```

... and for what it's worth, [here's the `malloc` manual showing that `malloc` returns `void *`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/malloc.html):

> ```
> void *malloc(size_t size);
> ```

---

In both cases, as described by [C11/6.3.2.3p1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p1) (the C11 standard):

> A pointer to void may be converted to or from a pointer to any object type. A pointer to any object type may be converted to a pointer to void and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer.

```
int *p = malloc(...); // A conversion occurs here; `void *` as returned by malloc is converted to `int *`
free(p);              // ... and the reverse of the conversion occurs here, to complete the cycle mentioned in C11/6.3.2.3p1
```

**NOTE** (in case you missed it the first time): [You should not cast the return value of `malloc` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc). After all, you don't need to cast it when you pass it to `free`, right?

Comment: I already studied K&R, and I'm aware of the fact that `free` takes a `void*`, I just wanted to make sure that the document is inaccurate by asking on SO.

Comment: From the article I quote: **"Besides the type void * which is mentioned in the next section, the  Standard has introduced the type long double."**. As you can see, they are aware of **void*** and the **Standard**. So it's not a matter of being old.

Comment: Well, now you know... and like some of my questions which are of a similar "I need validation" nature, I reckon this question will be (incorrectly) closed, and then later deleted. Let me know when it is, because this question should stay. Yes, the article mentions the standard and K&R2E, yet still maintains that portability prior to those resources is necessary... Back in those days was the case, but not now, especially for "Unix-like OSes" (which POSIX/the Open Group defines).

Comment: I want to point out that the resource is not *wrong*; in fact, from a historical point of view, considering the *historical definition of C* prior to C89, and even during the transitional period between C89 and C99 for any systems which still used the old pre-C89 compilers, this document has some *truth*. You'd be hard-pressed finding such compilers nowadays, so this is a non-concern... and for any C89, C99 or C11 implementation *this is wrong*. It's *invalid* because it's possibly wrong, not because it's always wrong (because after all, sometimes it's right).